# Rename folder on RemoteServer

Tags: shell, batch-file, remote-server, batch-rename

I am calling a .bat file which contains the following command

**net use \\128.545.k.k\E_Drive /user:Username psw to connect to a remote server.**

I would like to rename a folder on the remote server i am connected to

ren \\128.545.k.k\E:\abc rename **abc** folder to **xyz**.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

[Duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/1038729/rename-folder-on-remote-server/1038743)

If you have mapped \\128.545.k.k\**E_Drive** then use that in your ren command (not **E:**):

```
ren \\128.545.k.k\E_Drive\abc xyz
```